# Possible work-flows in  distributed version controlle

Tags: version-control, models, dvcs

What are the possible project models in distributed version control? Are there any better article to explain models like Pull only, Shared push, Single source ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [successful branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) article is a good start, even if it deals first with branching, before mentioning the collaborative aspect.
It pays to be clear on the branching model first, in order to know what will be published (pull/pushed), and what will not (private branches).

The distributed workflows are [introduced in the GitBook](http://book.git-scm.com/3_distributed_workflows.html), and detailed in [Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/ch5-1.html), where they are called (and this is not an exhaustive list):

- **Centralized Workflow**

[image: Centralized Workflow]

- **Integration-Manager Workflow**

[image: Integration-Manager Workflow]

- **Dictator and Lieutenants Workflow**

[image: Dictator and Lieutenants Workflow]

Comment: Are all these models possible with mercurial also?

Comment: @Jayantha: pretty much, yes, and the basic model is described in HgInit: http://hginit.com/02.html